# How to change the background in PageViewController dynamically?

Tags: swift, swift4, background-color, uipageviewcontroller, fade

I'm trying to fade the background color in a `PageViewController` dynamically. I want to fade the color from on page to the other.

So far, I tried to utilize the underlying `scrollView` of the `PageViewController` by implementing the function `scrollViewDidScroll` and setting the backgroundcolor of the `scrollview`.

Have a look at the following code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    guard lowerIndex >= 0, upperIndex < colors.count else { return }
    let percentComplete = (offset / CGFloat(colors.count)) / (scrollView.frame.width / CGFloat(colors.count))
    scrollView.backgroundColor = fadeFromColor(fromColor: colorCurrent, toColor: colorAfter, withPercentage: percentComplete)
}
```

This function uses the custom function fadeFromColor, which is defined as following:

```
func fadeFromColor(fromColor: UIColor, toColor: UIColor, withPercentage: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    var fromRed: CGFloat = 0.0
    var fromGreen: CGFloat = 0.0
    var fromBlue: CGFloat = 0.0
    var fromAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

    fromColor.getRed(&fromRed, green: &fromGreen, blue: &fromBlue, alpha: &fromAlpha)

    var toRed: CGFloat = 0.0
    var toGreen: CGFloat = 0.0
    var toBlue: CGFloat = 0.0
    var toAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

    toColor.getRed(&toRed, green: &toGreen, blue: &toBlue, alpha: &toAlpha)

    // calculate the actual RGBA values of the fade colour
    let red = (toRed - fromRed) * withPercentage + fromRed
    let green = (toGreen - fromGreen) * withPercentage + fromGreen
    let blue = (toBlue - fromBlue) * withPercentage + fromBlue
    let alpha = (toAlpha - fromAlpha) * withPercentage + fromAlpha

    // return the fade colour
    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
}
```

Currently I'm having problems to get the correct color at the right time.
Do you have a better idea to resolve my problem? Or do you think that at least my idea is correct?